# a set of pairwise commuting polynomials

Tags: polynomials

The set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots\}$ has the following properties:

- any two of these polynomials commute
- for any $n\ge 0$ there is exactly one polynomial of degree $n$ inside

Is this the only example? If not, is there a general form of such sets? I was thinking of this problem during a long flight, it seems very natural and might have been investigated, but I didn't found this result so far.

---

The above question has a negative answer - as flawr mentioned (see below), the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind are another example.

Also, Chris Culter pointed out, that we can replace any polynomial $f$ in our "good" set with a conjugate of the form $\sigma f \sigma^{-1}$, where $\sigma(x)=ax+b$ with $a\neq 0$.

---

So now, **a conjecture:**

$\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots\}$ **and** $\{T_0,T_1,T_2,\dots\}$ **and the conjugates among them are the only examples.**

---

---

Is the above conjecture true? Is such a thing already known?

---

---

Edit after a clarification request:

The field is $\mathbb{R}$.

I consider polynomials of real coefficients and one real variable.

Polynomials $P$ and $Q$ commute, if $P(Q(x))=Q(P(x))$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "any two of these polynomials commute" -- Under what operation, exactly? And polynomials over what? Not to say you're wrong necessarily but this is the exact topic that can get very very finicky depending on your mathematical sophistication - this question, for example, seems right on the verge of certain group- and ring-theoretic topics (abelian groups, free groups, cyclic groups, polynomials over rings, etc.) which could be broached, but they might be a bit above your level all depending.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every such polynomial chain is similar to (exactly one of) the power polynomials $\{x^1,x^2,\ldots\}$ or the Chebyshev polynomials $\{T_1, T_2,\ldots\}$.

---

Doing some internet digging, I found that the result was discovered by Block and Thielman; there's a nice overview of commuting polynomials, leading up to the result, in this article:
https://digitalworks.union.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1784&context=theses

The theorem itself appears on p33, as the  Block-Thielman theorem.  I present my own streamlined version of the results below.

In detail, you can establish that:

1. For any quadratic polynomial $q(x)$, and for every degree $k$, there is at most one degree-$k$ polynomial that commutes with $q$.

   It follows that a chain of polynomials (which mutually commute and have exactly one term of each degree) is uniquely determined by its quadratic term (!).
2. Every quadratic polynomial is similar to a unique monic polynomial of the form $x^2+c$.
3. In a chain, the value of $c$ must be equal to 0 or -2. In the first case, the chain is similar to the power chain. In the second case, it's similar to the Chebyshev chain.

Here's a sketch of how to prove #3 once you know #1 and #2. Take a chain $\{p_1, p_2, p_3, \ldots\}$, which by #1 we know is uniquely determined by its quadratic  $p_2$. By #2, $p_2$ is similar to a monic quadratic of the form $x^2+c$. Apply that similarity transform to every term in the chain, obtaining a new chain:

$$\{q_1, x^2+c, q_3, q_4, \ldots\}$$

and consider the degree-three term $q_3$. Because $q_3$ commutes with $x^2 + c$, we get a functional equation stating that the following two polynomials are equal everywhere:

$$q_3\circ q_2 = q_2\circ q_3$$

When two polynomials are equal, their coefficients must be equal. Hence we have a system of six equations relating $c$ to the coefficients of $q_3(x)$. ($q_m\circ q_n$ has degree $m+n$.)

The equations simplify. In fact, we can use the fact that $q_3$ commutes with $x^2+c$ to solve for all of $q_3$'s coefficients (see below).  The rest of the system tells us that $c$ was in fact highly constrained:

$$c(c+2) = 0$$

That is, $c=0$ or $c=-2$. At a higher level, this shows that a chain of polynomials can only exist when its quadratic term is similar to $x^2$ or to $x^2-2$— nothing else.

In the first case, the quadratic is similar to $x^2$, so the chain is similar to the power chain (by uniqueness #1). In the second case, the quadratic is similar to $x^2-2$. This is in turn similar to the second Chevyshev polynomial $T_2(x)=2x^2-1$, through the similarity $\alpha(x)=2x$, so the chain is similar to the Chebyshev chain.

---

We can derive the coefficients of $q_3$ from the fact that it commutes with $x^2+c$.  Take note of the following facts:

4. For even polynomials $f(-x)=f(x)$, all the odd coefficients vanish. For odd polynomials $f(-x)=-f(x)$, all the even coefficients vanish. (N.B. Not all polynomials are odd or even functions.)
5. If a polynomial commutes with a degree $n$ *monic* polynomial, then its leading coefficient must be a root of $x^{n-1}-1$.

Then here's what we know about $q_3$:

- It commutes with $(x^2+c)$, obeying the equation  $$q_3\circ(x^2+c) = (x^2+c)\circ q_3$$
- By #5, its leading coefficient must be 1 (the only root of $x-1$).
- By expanding out the equation, we find that $q_3(x)^2 \equiv q_3(-x)^2$. Hence $q_3(x)$ must be an odd or even function $=\pm q_3(-x)$. But it's cubic, so its degree-3 term can't vanish (see #4) — we conclude it's odd.
- It's an odd function, so its only nonzero coefficients are its leading coefficient and its linear coefficient. (See #4)
- The linear coefficient $b_1$ is the only unknown; our system lets us solve for it, finding $3c = 2b_1$.

---

Comment: It was a hard choice to choose one of these two answers to award the bounty (it can't be split, unfortunately). I decided for this one, as it contains a reference to the complete solution with some additional results as well.

Answer (score 3):

the examples you mentioned are not the only examples: Consider the [Chebyshev Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $\{T_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$. These have the property that

$$T_n(T_m(x)) = T_{nm}(x)$$

and therefore they commute, but they are not repeated compositions of themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is YES to all your questions : yes it is already known, and I'm pretty certain that I've already seen here on MSE if not a proof, at least a mention of it. But I can't seem to find it back so I rewrite a proof here.

Let $(f_k)_{k\geq 0}$ be a sequence of polynomials with $\deg(f_k)=k$
and $f_i(f_j(x))=f_j(f_i(x))$ for any $i,j$. Using a suitable conjugation, we may assume

$$f_0(x)=1\tag{1}$$

Then, for any $i$ we have $f_i(1)=1$, or in other words

$$f_i(x)=1+(x-1)g_i(x)\tag{2}$$

for some $g_i$ of degree $i-1$. There are two constants $c$ and $d$ such that $g_2(x)=cx+d$ (note that $c\neq 0$). It follows that $f_2(x)=cx^2+(d-c)x+1-d$, and hence $f_1(f_2(x))=g_1f_2(x)+1-g_1=(cg_1)x^2+g_1(d-c)x+1-g_1d$ while
$f_2(f_1(x))=(cg_1^2)x^2+g_1(d+c-2g_1)x+(g_1^2-g_1)c+1-g_1d$. Comparing the leading coefficients and using $cg_1\neq 0$, we deduce that $g_1=1$, so

$$
f_1(x)=x \tag{3}
$$

There are three constants $k,l,m$ such that $g_3=kx^2+lx+m$. It follows that $f_3(x)=kx^3 + (l-k)x^2 + (m-l)x + 1-m$, and hence

$$
\begin{array}{lcrrrr}
kf_2(x)^3 & = & (kc^3)x^6  + 3kc^2(d-c)x^5 & + 3kc(c^2+d^2-3cd+c)x^4
& + k(d-c)(c^2+d^2-8cd+6c)x^3 & + \ldots \\
(l-k)f_2(x)^2 & = &    & + (l-k)c^2 x^4
& + 2c(l-k)(d-c)x^3 & + \ldots \\
f_3(f_2(x)) & = & (kc^3)x^6  + 3kc^2(d-c)x^5 & + c\big(lc+k(3c^2+3d^2-9cd+2c)\big) x^4
& + (d-c)\big(2cl+k(c^2+d^2-8cd+4c)\big)x^3 & + \ldots \\
\end{array}
$$

Similarly,

$$
\begin{array}{lcrrr}
cf_3(x)^2 & = & (k^2c)x^6  + 2kc(l-k)x^5  + c(k^2+l^2+2mk-4kl)x^4
& + 2c(-l^2+(k+m)l+k(1-2m))x^3 & + \ldots \\
(d-c)f_3(x) & = &
& + k(d-c)x^3 & + \ldots \\
f_2(f_3(x)) & = & (k^2c)x^6  + 2kc(l-k)x^5  + c(k^2+l^2+2mk-4kl)x^4
& + \big(kd+2c(-l^2+(k+m)l+k(\frac{1}{2}-2m))\big)x^3 & + \ldots \\
\end{array}
$$

We thus obtain the system

$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{lcl}
kc^3 &=& k^2c \\
3kc^2(d-c) &=& 2kc(l-k) \\
c\big(lc+k(3c^2+3d^2-9cd+2c)\big)  &=& c(k^2+l^2+2mk-4kl) \\
(d-c)\big(2cl+k(c^2+d^2-8cd+4c)\big)  &=& kd+2c(-l^2+(k+m)l+k(\frac{1}{2}-2m)) \\
\end{array}\right.
$$

Remembering that $ck\neq 0$, the first line yields $k=c^2$, the second then yields $l=\frac{c}{2}(3d-c)$, and the third yields $m=\frac{-c^2+6(1-d)c+3d(d+2)}{8}$. The fourth equation then becomes equivalent to $c^5 + (3d - 6)c^4 + (3d^2 - 12d + 8)c^3 + (d^3 - 6d^2 + 8d)c^2=0$, which nicely factorizes as $c^2(d+c-4)(d+c-2)(d+c)=0$. So $d$ must be one of $4-c,2-c$ or $-c$.

When $d=4-c$, putting $\sigma(x)=\frac{(4-d)x-(2-d)}{2}$, we have
$\sigma f_2\sigma^{-1}(x)=2x^2-1$ and $\sigma f_3\sigma^{-1}(x)=4x^3-3x$.

When $d=2-c$, putting $\sigma(x)=(2-d)x-(1-d)$, we have
$\sigma f_2\sigma^{-1}(x)=x^2$ and $\sigma f_3\sigma^{-1}(x)=x^3$.

When $d=-c$, putting $\sigma(x)=d(1-x)$, we have
$\sigma f_2\sigma^{-1}(x)=x^2$ and $\sigma f_3\sigma^{-1}(x)=x^3$.

So we have shown that (up to conjugation) we can assume either (a) $f_2(x)=x^2, f_3(x)=x^3$, (b) $f_2(x)=T_2(x)$,  $f_3(x)=T_3(x)$.

Suppose we are in case (a). Let $n\geq 4$. Then $f_n(x^2)=f_n(x)^2$. Comparing the leading coefficients, we see that  $f_n$ is monic. Let $z\in{\mathbb C}$ be a complex root of $f_n$. Since $f_n(x^2)=f_n(x)^2$, we see that $z^2$ is a root of $f_n$ also, and by induction every $z^{2^m}$ for $m\geq 1$ is a root of $f_n$. Since there are only finitely many roots, by the pigeonhole principle we can find $m\lt m'$ such that $z^{2^m}=z^{2^{m'}}$, and if $z\neq 0$ then $z$ must be a root of unity. But a root of unity is of the form $exp(2pi r)$ where $r \in {\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$. Denote by $R$ the (possibly empty) subset of ${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$ of all arguments that can be obtained in this way. Because of $f_n(x^2)=f_n(x)^2$, $R$ is stable by division by $2$, so it is either empty or infinite (which is impossible). Thus $0$ is the only complex root of $f_n$, $f_n(x)=x^n$ and we are done in this case.

Suppose we are in case (b). Let $n\geq 4$. Then $f_n(T_2(x))=T_2(f_n(x))$. Comparing the leading coefficients, we see that the leading coefficient of $f_n$ is $2^{n-1}$. Write $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^{n-k}$ (so $a_0=2^{n-1}$). Then, for $1\leq d \leq n$ in the expansion of $f_n(T_2(x))-T_2(f_n(x))$, the coefficient of degree $2n-d$ in $x$ is of the form $-4a_0a_d+h(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{d-1})$ where $h$ is a polynomial in $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{d-1}$. Thus the value of $a_d$ can be deduced from the values of $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{d-1}$. It follows that there is at most one polynomial of degree $n$ commuting with $T_2$. But we already know that $T_n$ has this property, so $f_n=T_n$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace each polynomial $f(x)$ in your set with the conjugate $f'(x)=f(x-1)+1$. This will yield $\{2,x,x^2-2x+2,x^3-3x^2+3x,\ldots\}$.

A bit more generally, let $\sigma(x)=ax+b, a\neq0$ be an invertible polynomial. Then you can conjugate like so: $f'(x)=\sigma(f(\sigma^{-1}(x)))$.

Comment: very clever observation! I wonder if every example can be obtained this way