# Commutant of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, laurent-series

Let $Q$ a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ (or in $\mathbb{K}[X]$ with $\mathbb{K}$ a field of characteristic zero).

I wonder what is the commutant of $Q$, i.e. the set of polynomials $P$ such that $P \circ Q = Q \circ P$, where $\circ$ is the composition. More precisely, is there any works, any results on that topic ?

All the followings remarks also works in $\mathbb{K}[X]$, where the (formal) Bottcher coordinates are still defined. This holds because the characteristic of $\mathbb{K}$ is zero.

If $Q$ is constant or of degree $1$, the answer is easy. I suppose that $Q$ is of degree $d_0$, and $d_0$ greater than $1$. Conjugating $Q$ by an homothety, I suppose that the leading coefficient of $Q$ is $1$.

The constants polynomials commuting with $Q$ are its fixed points.

Let $d$ a natural integer. Using the Bottcher coordinates $\Phi$ at infinity, it is possible to show that for all integer $d$ there are exactly $d_0-1$ Laurent séries $L$ in $1/X$ of degree $d$ (i.e. $L = \sum_{k = - \infty}^d a_k X^k$ with $a_d \neq 0$) commuting with $Q$. Indeed, in these coordinates $Q$ is $X^{d_0}$, and $L$ must be $\zeta X^d$ where $\zeta^{d_0-1} = 1$. This gives the explicit formula $L(X) = \Phi^{-1}( \zeta \Phi(X)^d )$.

But it is not easy at all to caracterize when $L$ is a polynomial in X.

For instance, for the polynomial $Q = X^2 + 1$, I am tempted to say that a polynomial $P$ of degree greater than 0 commutes with $Q$ if and only if $P$ is of the form $P = Q\circ ... \circ Q$. The preceeding paragraphs shows that it is true if the degree of $P$ is a power of two, but it remains to show that $L(X) = \Phi^{-1}( \Phi(X)^d )$ is not a polynomial when $d$ is not a power of two.

Is it possible to calculate the commutant of $Q$ in this case ? Or in some simple cases where $Q$ is not conjugate to a Tchebychev polynomial or a power of $X$ ?

Comment: See the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184789/a-set-of-pairwise-commuting-polynomials): *For any quadratic polynomial $q(x)$, and for every degree $k$, there is at most one degree-$k$ polynomial that commutes with $q$.*

Comment: Thanks. It is nice to see that Bottcher coordinates are not necessary to show this result. But I would ideally like to understand more precisely the commutant of a polynomial which is not conjugate in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ to a power of X or a Tchebychev, for instance $X^2+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a detailed caracterisation of commutation for polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X]$. See the following article of Ritt : https://www.jstor.org/stable/1989297

The theorem says that two polynomials $P$ and $Q$ of degree greater than 1 commute if and only if, up to conjugacy in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ :

- The polynomials are powers of $X$ multiplied by roots of unity satisfying the appropriate relation
- The polynomials are Tchebychev polynomials
- The polynomials are iterates of a polynomial of the form $X R(X^r)$ multiplied by a $r$-root of unity

The example of $Q = X^2+1$ belongs to the third case with r=1, thus the commutant of $Q$ is formed by its iterates and the constant polynoms where the constant is a fixed point of $Q$.